# Wrong Wolfram|Alpha limit? $ f(x,y) = \frac {xy}{|x|+|y|} $ for $(x,y)\to(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, wolfram-alpha

I have this function:

$$ f(x,y) = \frac {xy}{|x|+|y|} $$

And I want to evaluate it's limit when $$ (x,y) \to (0,0)$$ My guess is that it tends to zero. So, by definition, if:

$$
\forall \varepsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0 \diagup \\ 0\lt||(x,y)||\lt \delta , \left|\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}\right| \lt \varepsilon
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac {xy}{|x|+|y|} = 0
$$
So:

$$
\left|\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}\right| = \frac{|xy|}{|x|+|y|}
= \frac{|x||y|}{|x|+|y|} \le 1 |y| \lt \delta
$$

So for any $$\delta \lt \varepsilon$$ the inequality is true. Hence, the limit exists and is equal to zero.

[Wolfram|Alpha says that the limit does not exist](https://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e8d7r3lvtvj). Am I wrong or is Wolfram|Alpha wrong?

Comment: It seems like another instance Wolfram|Alpha is wrong.

Comment: WA is wrong. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Note that it says "value may depend on $x,y$ path in complex space" -- it's not quite clear whether it's considering $(x,y)$ as a complex number or both $x$ and $y$ as complex numbers, but it doesn't matter since most of the proofs in the answers also work for complex $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Remember that you can point out the error to Wolfram|Alpha. At the bottom of every query, there's a link to send the company feedback.

Comment: When I run the query on W|A, I get a message saying `"Standard computation time exceeded..."` Might that have a bearing on the incorrect answer?

Comment: A couple of years later and... they've fixed it!
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+when+(x,y)-%3E(0,0)+of+xy%2F(%7Cx%7C%2B%7Cy%7C)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right, though you mix up the direction of proof (by what you write, you literally just show "if the limit exists, then it is $0$").

Given $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta=\epsilon$.
Assume $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ is a point with $|(x,y)|<\delta$. Then especially $0<r<\delta$ with $r:=\max\{|x|,|y|\}$ and hence 
$$ \left|\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}\right|=\frac{|x|\cdot|y|}{|x|+|y|}\le \frac{r^2}{r+0}=r<\delta<\epsilon,$$
as was to be shown, i.e. 
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}=0.$$

Answer (score 19):

Pretty simply, we have
$$
|xy|=\max(|x|,|y|)\min(|x|,|y|)\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
|x|+|y|\ge2\min(|x|,|y|)\tag{2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left|\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}\right|\le\frac{\max(|x|,|y|)}{2}\tag{3}
$$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left|\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}\right|\le\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\max(|x|,|y|)}{2}=0\tag{4}
$$

Answer (score 9):

You are right, wolfram is wrong. It might happen...

Only you should correct your exposition of the definition. You say:

```
By definition, if blah blah, then bleh bleh
```

you should say:

```
By definition, blah blah, if bleh bleh
```

In fact you prove bleh bleh to have blah blah.

Comment: Like your choice of words. *bleh blah*

Answer (score 7):

The first thing to do when computing this kind of limits is trying to isolate a bounded expression.

Assuming $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ in what follows, we clearly have

$$
\left|\frac{y}{|x|+|y|}\right|\le 1.
$$

Therefore we can write

$$
-|x|\le\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}\le |x|
$$

and so

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}=0$$

follows by the squeezing theorem.

Comment: This can be extended to show that
$$
\left|\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}\right|\le\min(x,y)
$$
a nice complement to my answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** By the arithmetic-geometric inequality
$$
\frac{|xy|}{|x|+|y|}\leq\frac{\sqrt{|xy|}}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Any function $f(x,y)$ such that $|f(x,y)|\le |x|$ has limit $0$ at $(0,0).$ And we have that here:

$$\left | \frac{xy}{|x|+|y|} \right | = |x|\left | \frac{|y|}{|x|+|y|} \right | \le |x|.$$